# eclipse-python IDE if else matching line/indicator

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

I am using eclipse pydev IDE for coding python. I found that by default I am not able to see any lines/dotted lines/indicator which basically shows which "if" statement is being matched for which "else" statement. This is usually shown as a dotted line in other IDEs. I really miss this since if the condition branches out its difficult for me to figure out the matching if else clause. Is there is an option to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, eclipse/pydev do not have column pos indicators. However you can get them with the [EditBox](http://editbox.sourceforge.net/) plugin for eclipse.
I had to customize a little bit this tool because its defaults are too colourfoul. You have to eliminate everything except some of the square lines to get the typical tabulation vertical dotted line marker.